# Expand menu (movieclip) and music in music setting error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have make a menu in Flash that can expand and there music setting inside.

The music plays when the application starts. To stop the music you must expand the menu and click the music icon.

- It's working fine after I open the program and stop the music.
- And it's working if I want to play again.

But there's problems after that: 
 
I can't stop the music again and the music playing double in background.

This is my FLA file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DpqdH64kDnI8xN6fBAt3pwi_bIRQ52mT/view?usp=drivesdk

Can anyone tell me the fault of my program? Thanks.

Comment: PS: No one should check entire FLA code just to answer this. Put the relevant code in the above question (use the [**`edit`**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47184859/edit) button under your tags)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About *"music playing double"* does your (audio) playback function create a `new` anything?
 (eg: `= new Sound` or `= new SoundChannel`)? If yes...

- Create your audio variables once outside of functions, then use your functions **only to** stop/start audio playback.
- Use `new Sound` only when **loading a new track**, once loaded then use one `SoundChannel` to play/stop that `Sound` object.
- You need a `Boolean` to keep track of whether a `Sound` is already playing or not. If `true` then don't send another `.play()` command (now gives two sounds to output/speakers).

See if the code logic below guides you toward a better setup:

```
//# declare variables globally (not trapped inside some function)
var snd_Obj :Sound;
var snd_Chann :SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

var snd_isPlaying :Boolean = false;

//# main app code
loadTrack("someSong.mp3"); //run a function, using "filename" as input parameter


//# supporting functions
function loadTrack (input_filename :String) : void 
{ 
    snd_Obj = new Sound(); 
    snd_Obj.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finished_LoadTrack);
    snd_Obj.load( input_filename ); //read from function's input parameter
}

function finished_LoadTrack (event:Event) : void 
{ 
    snd_Chann = snd_Obj.play(); //# Play returned Speech convert result
    snd_Obj.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded);

    //# now make your Play and Stop buttons active
    btn_play.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, play_Track);
    btn_stop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stop_Track);

}

function play_Track (event:Event) : void 
{ 
    //# responds to click of Play button 

    if(snd_isPlaying != true) //# check if NOT TRUE, only then start playback
    { 
        snd_Chann = snd_Obj.play(); 
        snd_isPlaying = true; //# now set TRUE to avoid multiple "Play" commands at once
    }
}

function stop_Track (event:Event) : void 
{
    //# responds to click of Play button 
    snd_Chann.stop();
    snd_isPlaying = false; //# now set FALSE to reset for next Play check
}
```